# Jackson сериализация POJO поля в escaped-json-string

Tags: java, json, строки, jackson, escape

Есть POJO:

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ExamplePojo {
    private String stringField;
    private SubPojo subPojo;

    @Data
    public static class SubPojo {
        private String subPojoStringField;
        private Integer answer;
    }
}
```

Мне надо при сериализации этого объекта через Jackson ObjectMapper поле `SubPojo subPojo` сериализовывать не как объект, а как экранированную json-строку. Т.е. при сериализации я хочу увидеть не

```json
"subPojo":{"subPojoStringField":"Substring","answer":42}
```

а

```json
"subPojo":"{\"subPojoStringField\":\"Substring\",\"answer\":42}"
```

Как это сделать "наиболее правильно"? Я нашел, что на поля объектов можно вешать аннотацию `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize` для указания кастомного сериализатора. Для этого написал свой костыльный сериализатор:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ToEscapedJsonStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(serialized);
    }
}
```

И накинул в `ExamplePojo` аннотацию:

```java
@Data
public class ExamplePojo {
    private String stringField;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToEscapedJsonStringSerializer.class)
    private SubPojo subPojo;

    @Data
    public static class SubPojo {
        private String subPojoStringField;
        private Integer answer;
    }
}
```

Тем самым получив ожидаемый результат, но в собственном сериализаторе пришлось создать новый инстанс `ObjectMapper` и самому его "доконфигурировать", что не очень-то правильно, тк "верхний" `ObjectMapper` может иметь свои конфигурации и надо бы использовать их, а не писать свои. Можно ли как-то переписать этот `ToEscapedJsonStringSerializer` на использование `ObjectMapper`, которым сериализовывали "на самом верху"? Можно ли решить эту задачу с использованием каких-то built-in сериализаторов? Например, пробовал использовать `@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)` и получал:

```json
"subPojo":"ExamplePojo.SubPojo(subPojoStringField=Substring, answer=42)"
```

---

Тест для проверки:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class UsageTest {
    @Test
    public void main() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ExamplePojo examplePojo = new ExamplePojo();
        examplePojo.setStringField("My string value");

        ExamplePojo.SubPojo subPojo = new ExamplePojo.SubPojo();
        subPojo.setSubPojoStringField("Substring");
        subPojo.setAnswer(42);
        examplePojo.setSubPojo(subPojo);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(examplePojo);

        String expected = "{\"stringField\":\"My string value\",\"subPojo\":\"{\\\"subPojoStringField\\\":\\\"Substring\\\",\\\"answer\\\":42}\"}";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, serialized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

После кружки чая нашел, как можно было вытащить "верхний" ObjectMaper...

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ToEscapedJsonStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonGenerator.getCodec();
        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(serialized);
    }
}
```

Но всё ещё буду благодарен, если кто-то найдет, как провернуть такое, используя уже готовые классы.

Comment: Беглое гугление приводит к мысли, что вы уже нашли единственно правильное решение)